# Using Selenium to test empty text field

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium

So I am testing a web client which communicates with an engine that does something to a text file that I upload. So basically, I choose a file to upload, once this file is uploaded i can press start and the engine does its thing and returns a result. I have an option to name the result such that when the result comes back it will be have a predefined name. I am trying to test the scenario where no name is provided. When the page first starts up the name field has a default value call "domainLM". I grabbed the element using

```
self.nameField = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='DomainLM']")
```

and then I cleared the field using

```
self.nameField.clear()
```

The problem is, once this line finish executing and I move on to upload a file, the default name pops back up in the name field, is there a way to permanently keep the name field blank? This also happens when I tried to uncheck some checkboxes, they recheck themselves when I move on in my test case. Does anyone know what the problem is? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Why you want to erase default value in input field instead of just sending your value to this field?

Comment: try adding a space to that empty field

Comment: @HassanMehmood Adding a space isn't technically blank.

Comment: @Andersson OP said that his test case is to test an empty filename.

Comment: Are you sure the filename is actually there? Some fields have a default value that shows up in the field as a guide or explanation but if you don't replace the default value it ends up as blank.

Comment: @JeffC Yeah, I also tried this manually, the name field remains empty and it gave me an error complaining about the fact that it needs an actual filename to proceed, which is what I expect. But when I do it in selenium, it just passes with no error. I can also see the filename pop back up.

Comment: So I found a simple "brute force fix", instead of using clear(), I just used pyautogui and pressed backspace until the name field is empty